# Javascript .replace() not working in Chrome globally

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, methods, replace

I've been working on a simple jQuery plugin that will basically template json data. It allows you to supply an html template url, data url and target for where you would like data to be displayed. The problem that I am having is that when I do this:

```
var regex = new RegExp( '[['+ key +']]', 'g' );
tplHTML = tplHTML.replace( regex, this[key] );
```

It is only replacing the first case it finds rather than following the global flag.

Here is the page where the call is made to the plugin and also the data is displayed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title></title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style>
* { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; color: #666; font-weight: 100; line-height: 150%; font-size: 1.0em; }
.container { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
    .left { width: 460px; float: left; }
    .right { width: 400px; float: right; }

td, th { text-align: left; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid #f5f5f5; padding: 10px; font-size: .8em; }
.clear { clear: both; }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <table id="users">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <table id="comments">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>User id</th>
                <th>Comment</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/userData.js"></script>
<script src="js/templatize.ajax.js"></script>

<script>
$('#users').templatize({
    itemsURL: 'process/ajaxUsers.php?l=5&order=ASC',
    tplURL: 'tpl/usersTpl.php',
    targetHTML: '#users'
});

$('#comments').templatize({
    itemsURL: 'process/ajaxComments.php?l=5&order=ASC',
    tplURL: 'tpl/commentTpl.php',
    targetHTML: '#comments'
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the plugin code:

```
( function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.templatize = function( options ) {

        /*%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    Configuration Settings    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%*/
        var config = $.extend({
            debugging           :       false,
            targetHTML          :       '.container',
            output              :       '',
            tplURL              :       '',
            itemsURL            :       '',
            tpl                 :       '',
            items               :       ''
        }, options );

        init();

        /*%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    Initialize & Retrieve Data Objects    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%*/
        function init() {

            var tpl, itemsObj;

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: config.tplURL,
                data: 'json',
                async: false,
                success: function( info ) {
                    tpl = info; 
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: config.itemsURL,
                data: 'json',
                async: false,
                success: function( items ) {
                    itemsObj = items;   
                }
            });

            config.tpl = tpl;
            config.items = itemsObj; 

            templatize();

        }

        /*%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    Receive Data & Replace tags for template    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%*/
        function templatize() {

            var tplHTML = ''; 
            var i = jQuery.parseJSON( config.items );

            if( config.debugging ) {
                console.log( i );
            }

            $( i ).each( function() {

                tplHTML = config.tpl;

                for (var key in this) {

                    //tplHTML = tplHTML.replace('[['+ key +']]', this[key]);
                    var regex = new RegExp( '[['+ key +']]', 'g' );
                    tplHTML = tplHTML.replace( regex, this[key] );

                }

                config.output += tplHTML;
            });

            $( config.targetHTML ).append( config.output );

            if( config.debugging ) {
                console.log( 'Target for data placement: '+ config.targetHTML );
            }

        }

    };

}) ( jQuery );
```

Finally here is the template code:

```
<tr><td>[[id]]</td><td><a href="user.php?id=[[id]]">[[name]]</a></td><td>[[email]]</td><td>[[phone]]</td></tr>
```

I'm using a similar tagging structure format similar to smarty tags. I've been racking my brain for a while on this and researching various documentation and found no solutions that work for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Overall I just need to figure out a way to get javascripts .replace() method to replace not just the first instance of a match but all instances. I've tried a version that only seems compatible with Firefox where .replace(search, replacement, flags)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly I would think you intended your regex to use the variable `key` not the string `"key"`, so it should be:

```
new RegExp( '[[' + key + ']]', 'g' )
```

And secondly `[` has special meaning within a regex so it needs to be escaped:

```
new RegExp( '\\[\\[' + key + ']]', 'g' )
```

Because you are building your regex from a string you need a double backslash to escape each `[` so that for a `key` of, say `"id"`, the resulting regex will be `\[\[id]]`.

Comment: Thank you n, your correct I had been messing with it testing as many ways as I could think of hoping I'd hit the lottery and then forgot to change it back before posting to here. Thanks man!!! This has been bugging me for a while!!!